# Alternative way to left join in SQL ORACLE DB

Tags: sql, oracle, select, left-join, where-clause

if I run the query below query:

```
SELECT day.M_CMP_TYPO AS M_CMP_TYPO,
        day.M_SPTCV as M_SPTCV,
       day.M_CNT_VS2 AS M_CNT_VS2,
       day.M_CNT_ORG AS M_CNT_ORG,
       day.M_PL_CGR2 AS M_PL_CGR2,
       day.M_PL_CGU2 AS M_PL_CGU2,
       day.M_PL_CSFI2 AS M_PL_CSFI2,
       day.M_PL_FTFI2 AS M_PL_FTFI2,
       day.M_PL_RVR2 AS M_PL_RVR2,
       day.M_PL_RVU2 AS M_PL_RVU2,
       day.M_TRN_FMLY AS M_TRN_FMLY,
       day.M_TRN_GRP AS M_TRN_GRP,
       day.M_TRN_TYPE AS M_TRN_TYPE,
       day.M_CNT_VS2 AS M_CNT_VS2,
       day.M_C_CUR_PL AS M_C_CUR_PL,
       day.M_INSTRLABEL AS M_INSTRLABEL,
       day.M_NB AS M_NB,
       day.M_PL_INSCUR AS M_PL_INSCUR,
       day.M_TP_CNTRPLB AS M_TP_CNTRPLB,
       day.M_TP_PFOLIO AS M_TP_PFOLIO,
       day.M_ECO_PL AS M_ECO_PL,
       day.M_CNT_ID AS M_CNT_ID,
       day.M_ECO_PL_USD AS M_ECO_PL_USD,
       day.M_POS_CURR2 AS M_POS_CURR2,
       day.M_CURR2 AS M_CURR2,
       day.M_TP_QTYEQ AS M_TP_QTYEQ,
       day.M_TP_UQTYEQ AS M_TP_UQTYEQ,
       day.M_TP_LQTY32 AS M_TP_LQTY32,
       day.M_TP_UQTY AS M_TP_UQTY,


     --day.M_ECO_PL - daily.M_ECO_PL AS DAILY_VAR,
         --day.M_ECO_PL - month.M_ECO_PL AS MTD,
     day.M_ECO_PL - year.M_ECO_PL AS YTD,



--day.M_SPTCV * (day.M_ECO_PL - daily.M_ECO_PL) as DAILY_VAR_USD,
--day.M_SPTCV * (day.M_ECO_PL - month.M_ECO_PL) as MTD_USD,
day.M_SPTCV * (day.M_ECO_PL - year.M_ECO_PL) as YTD_USD



  FROM RT_PLVAR_REP day
  LEFT JOIN RT_PLVAR_REP year ON day.M_NB = year.M_NB
    --LEFT JOIN RT_PLVAR_REP month ON day.M_NB = month.M_NB
  --LEFT JOIN RT_PLVAR_REP daily ON day.M_NB = daily.M_NB

WHERE day.M_REF_DATA = 18
AND   year.M_REF_DATA = 20
--AND   month.M_REF_DATA = 0
--AND   daily.M_REF_DATA = 0
```

it returns the expected behavior, that means it returns 27 rows knowing that year.M_REF_DATA = 20 exists in the DB. else if I run this one I have no values. 
Since the M_REF_DATA=0 doesn't exist in the table I was expecting that this query returns 27 rows but the related columns should return null, but that's not the case.

I have tried to replace Where with AND it didn't work either. It returned 1728 rows which is a wrong answer, it should return 11. My question is why the left join isn't working as am expecting ?

```
SELECT day.M_CMP_TYPO AS M_CMP_TYPO,
            day.M_SPTCV as M_SPTCV,
           day.M_CNT_VS2 AS M_CNT_VS2,
           day.M_CNT_ORG AS M_CNT_ORG,
           day.M_PL_CGR2 AS M_PL_CGR2,
           day.M_PL_CGU2 AS M_PL_CGU2,
           day.M_PL_CSFI2 AS M_PL_CSFI2,
           day.M_PL_FTFI2 AS M_PL_FTFI2,
           day.M_PL_RVR2 AS M_PL_RVR2,
           day.M_PL_RVU2 AS M_PL_RVU2,
           day.M_TRN_FMLY AS M_TRN_FMLY,
           day.M_TRN_GRP AS M_TRN_GRP,
           day.M_TRN_TYPE AS M_TRN_TYPE,
           day.M_CNT_VS2 AS M_CNT_VS2,
           day.M_C_CUR_PL AS M_C_CUR_PL,
           day.M_INSTRLABEL AS M_INSTRLABEL,
           day.M_NB AS M_NB,
           day.M_PL_INSCUR AS M_PL_INSCUR,
           day.M_TP_CNTRPLB AS M_TP_CNTRPLB,
           day.M_TP_PFOLIO AS M_TP_PFOLIO,
           day.M_ECO_PL AS M_ECO_PL,
           day.M_CNT_ID AS M_CNT_ID,
           day.M_ECO_PL_USD AS M_ECO_PL_USD,
           day.M_POS_CURR2 AS M_POS_CURR2,
           day.M_CURR2 AS M_CURR2,
           day.M_TP_QTYEQ AS M_TP_QTYEQ,
           day.M_TP_UQTYEQ AS M_TP_UQTYEQ,
           day.M_TP_LQTY32 AS M_TP_LQTY32,
           day.M_TP_UQTY AS M_TP_UQTY,


         day.M_ECO_PL - daily.M_ECO_PL AS DAILY_VAR,
             day.M_ECO_PL - month.M_ECO_PL AS MTD,
         day.M_ECO_PL - year.M_ECO_PL AS YTD,



    day.M_SPTCV * (day.M_ECO_PL - daily.M_ECO_PL) as DAILY_VAR_USD,
    day.M_SPTCV * (day.M_ECO_PL - month.M_ECO_PL) as MTD_USD,
    day.M_SPTCV * (day.M_ECO_PL - year.M_ECO_PL) as YTD_USD



      FROM RT_PLVAR_REP day
      LEFT JOIN RT_PLVAR_REP year ON day.M_NB = year.M_NB
        LEFT JOIN RT_PLVAR_REP month ON day.M_NB = month.M_NB
      LEFT JOIN RT_PLVAR_REP daily ON day.M_NB = daily.M_NB

    WHERE day.M_REF_DATA = 18
    AND   year.M_REF_DATA = 0
    AND   month.M_REF_DATA = 0
    AND   daily.M_REF_DATA = 0
```

Comment: By saying `year.M_REF_DATA = 0` in your WHERE, you are requiring that value be present. Consider moving the ANDs to be under their respective ONs, or else wrap the clause in logic defining how to handle NULLs. For example: `NVL(year.M_REF_DATA, 0) = 0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the `from` and `where` clauses from the first query:

```
FROM RT_PLVAR_REP day LEFT JOIN
     RT_PLVAR_REP year
     ON day.M_NB = year.M_NB
WHERE day.M_REF_DATA = 18 AND year.M_REF_DATA = 20
```

The `where` clause turns the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.  The value of `year.M_REF_DATA` is NULL, so it fails the condition.

For a `LEFT JOIN`, the conditions should go in the `ON` clause:

```
FROM RT_PLVAR_REP day LEFT JOIN
     RT_PLVAR_REP year
     ON day.M_NB = year.M_NB AND year.M_REF_DATA = 20
WHERE day.M_REF_DATA = 18
```

Conditions on the first table should stay in the `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

For the outer joins, you need to move the filter criteria to the join:

```
  FROM RT_PLVAR_REP day
  LEFT JOIN RT_PLVAR_REP year 
    ON day.M_NB = year.M_NB
       AND year.M_REF_DATA = 0
  LEFT JOIN RT_PLVAR_REP month 
    ON day.M_NB = month.M_NB
       AND month.M_REF_DATA = 0
  LEFT JOIN RT_PLVAR_REP daily 
    ON day.M_NB = daily.M_NB
       AND daily.M_REF_DATA = 0
WHERE day.M_REF_DATA = 18
```

This tells the database that you only want to enforce that criteria when a row exists.